# Getting 403 when trying to update from Craft 3.3.20.1

Tags: updating

I just updated Craft Pro to 3.3.20.1 and went to run the next set of Craft updates (all from the cp). But now when accessing the updates page, the "checking for updates" spins continuously and I get these messages in my console:

```
POST https://www.my-domain.com/index.php?p=admin/actions/app/cache-updates 403 (Forbidden)

Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Everything else in the CP and front end seems to work ok. I'm not certain how/where to go next to fix this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I'm not certain how/if this is related but I do have a PHP error that *may have* occured around/at the time I tried to run this update:

`[17-Jan-2020 14:03:31 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/chroot/home/signamoc/craft/vendor/composer/../danielstjules/stringy/src/Create.php' (include_path='.:/opt/nexcess/php72u/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/nexcess/php72u/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /chroot/home/signamoc/craft/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66`

Comment: Are you doing this from an Admin account? And if not, does your user account have both the **General → Perform Craft CMS and plugin updates** and **Utilities → Updates** permissions?

Comment: Yes, I am doing this from an Admin account.

Comment: From your last edit, it sounds like you're missing some files that Craft relies on. Try running `composer update` from your project's root to get a fresh set of files?

Comment: Thanks Brad but exact same error after doing that.

Comment: Not an answer but a resolution... I still have no idea what the issue was but I pulled everything down and set this up locally. Updates ran fine locally. I then pushed everything back to the remote environment and now all is ok.